# How to change grip on firemonkey splitter

Tags: firemonkey

The default grip on the firemonkey splitter is a circle. Is there anyway to redraw the grip to something else? Styles don't seem to have any affect other than changing the color scheme. I tried intercepting OnPaint but that only seems to allow one to redraw the background.

If the grip can't be changed is there an alternative third-party firemonkey splitter that anyone is aware of?

Answer (score 1):

XE12:
drag&drop a rectangle to another control on your form that allow the rectangle as a sub control. (not directly that wont work!)
after that move it the splitter (that works well) with client align and modify the rectange as you like and at least set HitTest=false on rectangle.

Comment: Use cut and paste to move the rectangle into the splitter, drag in the structure panes doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The entire area of the splitter control responds to mouse events. That is the image of the grip has no special significance when moving the splitter via the mouse. Therefore use the OnPaint event to redraw the entire splitter control and include any necessary decoration that represents the grip.